# .Net DDos Attacks & Corporate User IPs

Tags: .net, iis, cloudflare, ddos

I did a research about this problem and couldn't find anything useful. Think of a corporate which has hundreds of users and try to reach our application. These users will have the same external ip address that goes to internet. How does the DDos preventing products ([CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) etc.) handle this?

In our .Net application, I think of writing a HttpModule which checks for `session_id` provided by the request cookie in each request because all users in that company will have the same ip but different `session_id` associated with them. I can't use IIS Dynamic IP Restriction too because of the same IP reason. What are my other options?

Comment: Why the -1s?? Is there something illogical in the question? No one has a real answer for it but you give -1s, nice keep it coming.. :)

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to Layer 7 attacks, CloudFlare has a way of determining whether a visitor is human or not.

CloudFlare's "I'm Under Attack" mode presents a challenge page like this:
[image: I'm Under Attack page]

It works to mitigate application layer attacks by presenting a Javascript challenge to the client. The client has to do computational work to solve that challenge in order to access the website. This levels the playing field between the work the server has to do to serve the website and the work the client has to do in order to access the site.

This is just one of the things CloudFlare does to perform DDOS mitigation, whilst this addresses Layer 7 attacks, CloudFlare has other functionality to offer [DDOS protection](https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos/) for Layer 3/4 attacks (though that's outside the scope of this question).

Comment: What if a user in company network with the external ip address of 1.1.1.1 solve that challange successfully and then another user with the same ip address (1.1.1.1) accesses the same website? Since these two users have the same ip address, I guess CloudFlare will treat these two users as the same user?